# Heroku: where did my gems go?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have been deploying a Rails 3.2 application to heroku for several weeks now. I have also been executing `rake` tasks on the Cedar stack where my application is located.

One day after a deploy I noticed that `rake` was no longer working. I get, for example, the following:

```
$:~/dev/my_project$ heroku run rake -T
Running `rake -T` attached to terminal... up, run.7566
bundler: command not found: rake
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

Trying to run commands with `bundle exec` yields the same results.

What I've tried:

1. `heroku run bundle install`. This works and informs me that gems were installed into `./vendor/bundle`. However, `heroku run ls ./vendor/bundle` yields only the following:

   `$:~/dev/my_project$ heroku run ls ./vendor/bundle/`

   `Running`ls ./vendor/bundle/`attached to terminal... up, run.3458`

   `bin  ruby`
2. `bundle package`. Although the deployment works it does not help my problem.
3. fiddling around with the [rubygems-bundler](https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler) gem (although I think this is now part of core bundler). This does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: try: `heroku run bundle show rake`

Comment: OK, output: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0

Comment: so *rake* gem is installed. it is strangely why it can't be run

Comment: my `heroku run rake` has succeeded

Answer (score 2):

On Heroku, gems are installed within the `vendor/bundle/ruby/<version>/gems` directory.  I just checked my Heroku instance and confirmed this.

Comment: OK, that's very interesting. My gems are definitely there, and the following command _does_ work: `heroku run ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake`. So any thoughts on why my app can't find `rake` in its PATH?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use `bundle exec rake task` because the gems are not in the users PATH.

Comment: I tried this already with no luck. I will update my question.